# c++ vector sorting with row and first column

Tags: sorting, vector, 2d

i have a 2d vector 10*100, with totally 1000 integers.
i want to sort the numbers by row and then by the first column containing every smallest number in each row after sorting by row.
then i want to find the smallest in the first column and store it in a new vector, at the same time erase this smallest num in that row, the rest numbers move forward and keep going in this way. but my code always has problems, i am a beginner, i can not fix it even after i have tried more than 20 times.
please help me out!!!

```
vector<int> final;
vector<int> firstcol;

for (int j=0; j<vec.size(); j++) {

     firstcol.push_back(vec[j][0]);
     cout << firstcol[j]<< endl;

}
int mini = *firstcol.begin();
for(int k=0; k< firstcol.size();k++){
     while (firstcol[k]< mini) {
          mini=firstcol[k];
          final.push_back(mini);
     }
     vec[k].erase(vec[k].begin());
}
cout << "mini:" << mini<<endl;


for (int m=0; m< final.size(); m++) {
    cout << final[m]<<endl;
}
```